# Why Eclipse p2site is asking for credentials?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, iis-7.5

I have a p2site hosted on my server to provide Eclipse Update Site. The server is running an IIS 7.5

I have the same p2site content stored and provided both in my production environment and in my staging environment (two separate servers, with identical characteristics).

From a couple of days, if I connect with my staging environment p2site from an Eclipse Indigo instance, I'm required to enter credentials, which has never happened before.

Moreover, if I manually download the zip archive and install my plugin from this local archive, I'm asked the credentials too.

I can guess, but I'm not sure, that the problem can be related to the following: in the last days we have added HTTPS enablement for our web site, and installed our certificate in the root certificates of Windows Server 2008 R2.

Anyone knows why Eclipse (Indigo, haven't tested the other platforms yet) is behaving in this way?

And how can I prepare my local zip archive / p2site to overcome this issue?

Thank you very much

cghersi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, I found the solution on my own: the problem was that for some reasons (that I cannot still recognize...) there was a DENY rule in the .NetAuthorization section for the verbs OPTION,HEAD.
It seems that Eclipse send exactly these kind of requests when looking for p2site and so these requests were rejected and Eclipse was asking for credentials for these requests.

Hope is can be useful in the future for other people.

cghersi